# Could not register service com.apple.coreservices.lsuseractivity.simulatorsupport

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

My OS version is 10.9.5 and i have installed Xcode Version 6.0.1 (6A317)

After installation on first time running Xcode it shows an error popup message
"/Applications/Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platform/iphonesimulator.platforms/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/dyld_sim is not owned by root"

Then i check this files owner by 'ls -l dyld_sim'
it shows root:wheel (Feeling nice)

But

When i try to run my simulator I get stuck on this.
A black screen appears and a popup shows an error msg "Invalid Device State"

When i open console it shows an error message

"Could not register service com.apple.coreservices.lsuseractivity.simulatorsupport: Failed to lookup com.apple.coreservices.lsuseractivity.simulatorsupport"

can anybody please help me about that, how can solve this problem

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by updating my OSX version to 10.10. Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Just relax solution is here
Open Terminal and just type this command
**sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer**

enjoy :)